# "Улитка" - задача на C++

Tags: c++

Та самая старая задача про улитку (на C++):

> Улитка ползёт по вертикальному шесту
> высотой h метров, поднимаясь за день
> на a метров, а за ночь спускаясь на b
> метров. На какой день улитка доползёт
> до вершины шеста?
>
> Программа получает на вход натуральные
> числа h, a, b и должна вывести одно
> натуральное число. Гарантируется, что
> a>b.

При решении этой задачи нельзя пользоваться условной инструкцией if и циклами.

---

Решение есть, но я не могу его понять. Можете подробно объяснить что и как?

решение:

> 1 + h0 / shag + (h0 % shag + shag - 1) / shag)

Comment: `(((h - a) + b) / (a - b)) - (a - b) ;` Ответ будет верным?

Answer (score 4):

Это же элементарная задача, часто встречающаяся на школьных олимпиадах по информатике( 7-8 класс! ). Решается она выводом нехитрой формулы:

**UPD:**
Спасибо пользователю [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp), который обнаружил фатальную ошибку в моем старом коде =)

**Исправленный вариант:**

```
double a = 5, 
       b = 4, 
       h = 1;

double days = ((h-a)>=0) ? h-a:0; 
days = ceil(days/(a-b))+1;
cout<<days<<endl;
```

Comment: @Asen, а Вы проверяли? 

Неправильно, при h = 1, a = 5, b = 4; ответ -3.000000. 

Но, не расстраивайтесь, второй вариант (1+h0/shag+(h0%shag+shag-1)/shag в целых числах (c double он, естественно, не компилируется)) дает такой же результат.

--

Вопрос остался без ответа, присоединяюсь к TC в непонимании таких формул.

@ablay, Вас кто-то обманул, скажите ему об этом.

--

Интересно, **плюсующие** просто безоговорочно верят отвечающим?

Comment: @avp, и правда фейл получается при таком раскладе...Спасибо, что сказали. Код исправил.

---
Я код проверял, конечно же! Просто почему-то не удосужился проверить при "ненормальных параметрах" =)

Comment: @avp ну так можно и про текущий вариант говорить что нет проверок на отрицательные числа. Подразумевается же что `h` больше или равно `a`

Answer (score 1):

```
 h0 = h - a;
```

вся высота шеста минус расстояние за день  = сколько надо дней в идеальном случае, т.е. без того, что она сползает

> shag = a - b;

сколько фактически проползает за сутки

> 1+h0/shag+(h0%shag+shag-1)/shag

формула, которая считает, то что надо =)

Comment: to Gotets:
>>формула, которая считает, то что надо =)

вот формулу я и не могу понять..

Comment: разбери ее по частям, 1 + h0 - для того, что бы вывести один день, если его будет достаточно для подъема.. и тд..

Comment: `h - a` - расстояние без последнего дня, когда улика залезет. Каждый предыдущий день, она будет сползать на `b` вниз после подъёма на `a`.

Comment: `1` - учет последнего дня; `h0/shag` - сколько **целых** шагов надо сделать; `(h0%shag+shag-1)/shag` - если `h0/shag` не делится нацело, подгоняем этот "орызок" до ещё одной `1`.

Answer (score -2):

Так будет правильно:

```
int h, a, b, res;

cin >> h >> a >> b;

res = (1 + (h - b - 1) / (a - b));

cout <<res;
```

Comment: А можете показать, на каких числах у вас ответ правильный, а в других ответах нет?

Comment: Если у вас есть компилятор на компе , можете попробовать

Comment: @Elyor05, речь про _конкретный_ пример. Сейчас в ответе лишь такая же непонятная формула что и в вопросе. Ты можешь доказать, что она чем-то отличается? И действительно правильно считает?